# What TTS engine does Microsoft Cortana use?

Tags: text-to-speech

It has emotion, It can stress a word in a sentence, it can sing a song. I was really impressed. I tried SAPI before, but it was very robotic.

Comment: System.Speech uses SAPI, it has been around for 20 years.  Cortana is a completely new design.

Comment: Cortana uses the speech engine built for Cortana. It's not the one .NET wraps around, as you've discovered. You can use Cortana from Windows Phone 8.1 apps (though possibly not with Cortana's voice specifically); when support comes to Windows 10, it seems likely it will be available to apps there as well. Otherwise, you could always try offering Microsoft a big bag of money to license it independently.

Comment: @JeroenMostert are there any updates about this topic?